# Excel choropleth map - find/get regions?

Tags: excel, charts, choropleth, geography

I'm working on an Excel file with municipalities in NL. With the data->data type->geography I can label those municipalities. Next, I can add a value and create a map (image on the left). There is however a snag: one municipality (orange, named Bunnik) is displayed as the village (part of that community) and I can't find any way to change that to the community. So my questions:

- is there a way to extract the correct regions/region names from a map?
- for this region you can see the community on the Wikipedia map (and also on the Excel map if you zoom in), is there a way to adjust this?

I tried to dissect the object (by inspecting the XML inside the xlsx file), but fail so far. Does anyone have a clue if my questions are at all achievable? I also tried VBA to check out the Chart object, but can't find anything there either.

[image: Map chart and municipality map]

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem to have a (simple) solution.
When you enter some data that has mutiple possibilities (try 'Utrecht'), you get the question mark (?) that gives you options to choose from.

However, Bunnik doesn't do this, and when you search for Bunnik in the dataselector, it only shows the one. (Sad extra: the added description even says it's a municipality.)

Comment: Little sidenote, but it's not really feasible: You could create an entire wikipedia page about the Municipality Bunnik, but I don't know how Excel verifies the data (assuming wikipedia doesn't delete your page first), so it will probably not show up any time soon.

Comment: Mmm, just read over your comments, the main issue is that I have no clue to know which regions Excel/MSFT knows/acknowledges. I tried to look on their Github pages (normally quite extensive), but nothing there: it's a black box and if it malfunctions there seems ot be no way to find out why/how to correct it. I think I'll build my own map add-in ;-).